# Injecting JavaScript codes into Windows 10 Web Hosted App (Project Westminster)?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-10, winjs

I'm trying to build an app for Windows 10 by the Web Hosted Apps approach, which is something cool .. but i'm facing a problem.
While i don't have access to the server ..  Can i 'inject' or sideload a JS code into my views ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer is you can't inject JS code into an web-based application made by project Westminster.. instead, using the typical web view is better for this mission.